# How to read PHP variable from an included file and echo it into textarea or input tags as {var_name}

Tags: php, variables, text, echo, box

My textarea field is like this:

`<textarea type="text" id="tos"><?php echo $tos; ?></textarea>`
The out put is:

```
Terms of Service of 'Website Name'
1. Term one
2. Term two
3. Term three
4. Term four
5. Term five
```

How to make `'Website Name'` as a php echo to get the site name from the included file or from database table instead of typing it manually? And the var in file is `$site`.

I can't use php tags inside the text box so how to use `{site}` or `{sitename}` to get value from the var `$site` in the included file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function `str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)` to replace the "Website Name" placeholder with the actual name of the website.

Like this:

```
<textarea type="text" id="tos"><?php $tos = str_replace("Website Name", $site, $tos); echo $tos; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I had to use it like this to make it work:
``` <textarea type="text" id="tos"><?php $tos = str_replace("Website Name", $site, $tos); echo $tos; ?></textarea> ```

Comment: This trick is good but I don't think I achieved what I want!
the var like ` {var} ` inside text boxes must read value automatically
like using php with ` echo $var; `